# How to optimize F# programs generally

Tags: performance, optimization, f#

I have an interpreter for a lisp-style language in F#, and have just gotten into the optimization phase. Simple tests of the evaluator reveal that I need to optimize it in an extreme manner. However, I don't have a general background in F# performance or optimization.

Are there any good general knowledge resources for F# program optimization? Particularly useful are tips of keeping cache coherency and surprising primitive performance issues. A cursory search hasn't revealed much on the internet.

Thank you!

Comment: There's no solution for all problems. If you describe a concrete issue, people will try to help you out.

Comment: You optimize F# programs the same way as any other programs: by profiling and then trying to speed up the parts of the code that make up biggest part of time.

Comment: If you have an interpreter then the best optimization (to improve the run-time performance of the code it generates) is surely to convert it into a compiler.

Comment: I was really just trying to ask what existing resources are available to help build the knowledge background necessary to understand how to optimize existing F# code / algorithms / program structure as well as how to spot inefficient F# code / idioms in the first place. I'm mostly looking for which books and tutorials have info relevant to that. Should I repost the question in that form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Performance optimization tricks are all myths. As @svick said, it's no better way than profiling your program, identifying hot spots and optimizing them using concrete benchmarks.

Since you asked, here is some information floating around:

- A bunch of good answers about F# performance: [C# / F# Performance comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144227/c-sharp-f-performance-comparison)
- Using inline for performance optimization: [Use of `inline` in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754862/use-of-inline-in-f)
- Using structs instead of records for better performance: http://theburningmonk.com/2011/10/fsharp-performance-test-structs-vs-records/
- Array-oriented programming for performance-critical code: http://sharp-gamedev.blogspot.com/2010/03/thoughts-about-f-and-xbox-games.html
- Concrete case studies of performance optimization:

  [FSharp runs my algorithm slower than Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850243/fsharp-runs-my-algorithm-slower-than-python)

  [F# seems slower than other languages... what can I do to speed it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794138/f-seems-slower-than-other-languages-what-can-i-do-to-speed-it-up)