# Array indexer signature returns object - does it box?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, indexer

I stumbled on the [fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133859/get-a-reference-to-a-struct-inside-array) that the indexer `this[int index] { get; }` works differently for an array of structs than it does for a List of structs. Namely, that the indexer in the case of an `T[]` returns a reference to the element within the array whereas the indexer in the case of a `List<T>` returns a copy of the element.

This is a very big semantic and performance difference, and I'm glad that `T[]` allows us to work around the performance limitation of `List<T>`.

However, I'm puzzled by the actual implementation. The [code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,251c99c8419d33d4) for `Array` in the .net reference sources reads thus:

```
Object IList.this[int index] {
    get { return GetValue(index); }
    set { SetValue(value, index); }
}
```

Where `GetValue` is defined as follows:

```
public unsafe Object GetValue(int index)
{
    if (Rank != 1)
       throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_Need1DArray"));
    Contract.EndContractBlock();
    TypedReference elemref = new TypedReference();
    InternalGetReference(&elemref, 1, &index);
    return TypedReference.InternalToObject(&elemref);
}
```

The return type of the indexer is `Object`, implying that boxing will take place.

So my question is, can I be certain that no boxing will occur when I access an element of a `T[]` where `T` is a struct?

I assume that the compiler and/or CLR treat Array specially, and don't actually bother with the signature of the indexer. Is this correct? Is there a fuller discussion of this somewhere?

Comment: `IList.SomeMethod` is an [implicit intefrace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/143405/1997232) implementation. It's a way of telling *"this method exists if object is classified as `IList`"*. It will only be used if you specifically request it, e.g. in case of indexer `((IList)someArray)[x]`. Accessing array indexer directly (e.g. `someArray[x]`) is another thing, you won't find sources for any method because there is none.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Namely, that the indexer in the case of an T[] returns a reference to the element within the array

Not really. It's more that there isn't an indexer for arrays - instead an *element-access* expression represents an array access instead of an element access (sections 7.6.6.1 and 7.6.6.2 of the C# 5 spec respectively).

There's a very significant difference between these two - in particular, an array access is classified as a *variable*, whereas an indexer access is classified as a *value*.

It's very similar to the difference between a property and a field - they both have the same syntax for access, but a property invokes a function member and returns a value, whereas a field access just yields the variable.

> So my question is, can I be certain that no boxing will occur when I access an element of a `T[]` where `T` is a struct?

If you're accessing it *as* a `T[]`, sure. The indexer you looked at is only used when you're viewing the array as an `IList`. So if you use:

```
IList array = new int[2];
object x = array[0];
```

then yes, that'll box the value... but if you write

```
int[] array = new int[2];
int x = array[0];
```

then that won't, and it won't be accessing that indexer code or the `GetValue` method at all.

Comment: Another way to look at it: `System.Array` is like a base type of all arrays. The implementation of `IList.this[int index]` in this base type exists so arrays will implement `System.Collections.IList`, not for regular element accesses.

Comment: Great, thanks. A follow up question - is there anything in Array.cs that is executed when i call array[index]? Or is that all implemented directly by the CLR?

Comment: @bright: All in the CLR, as far as I'm aware. There's IL specifically for array access, although I can't remember the op names offhand.

Comment: @JonSkeet, found it - ldelem.<type>. Thanks.