# pass ref as function argument inside a ternary operator

Tags: c#, function, syntax, reference

I have this function:

```
void TakeHit(ref Player player){
    //...
}
```

And I have 2 Players called `red` and `blue`. Suppose there is a boolean `isRed` that says if the Player that is going to take the hit is `red` (true) or `blue` (false):

```
bool isRed = //...
TakeHit( /* what do I write here in a ternary operator??? */ );
```

---

I tried some syntaxes and this one seemed to compile

```
TakeHit(ref isRed ? ref red : ref blue);
```

although I didn't test since it looks super wierd and I'm asking just out of curiosity since a simple `if` can replace the ternary operator option.

Comment: Different question, so not exactly a duplicate, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48136948) shows the correct syntax for ref within a ternary. You were so close.

Comment: Does `TakeHit(ref (isRed ? ref red : ref blue));` work?

Comment: Yes @rory.ap, it's exactly the solution.