# Reference that tabulates which F# types are value types and which are reference types

Tags: .net, f#

Is there a good reference that tabulates which F# types are value types and which are reference types?  Alternatively, is there a good way to query a type to determine which it is?  Yes, I know that things that are classes are reference types and things that are structs are value types.  At the same time, this distinction isn't always intuitive to me with F# types.  For example, [tuple types are reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410710/why-is-the-new-tuple-type-in-net-4-0-a-reference-type-class-and-not-a-value-t).  Evidently, so are record types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always check whether something is a value type using F# Interactive:

```
typeof<int * int>.IsValueType
```

As you mentioned, tuples are reference types and so this returns `false`.

I agree that the difference is not always clear. In general, most types that you work with in F# are reference types (and all F# types that you define with the exception of [struct types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233233.aspx)).

- Primitive types (numerical and booleans) are value types
- But `string` is a reference type
- There are a couple of struct types defined in .NET like `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` and also `KeyValuePair` (this is sometimes confusing as this is quite similar to tuple).
- F# tuples, records, discriminated unions, lists, arrays are all reference types
- F# object types are also reference types unless they are marked as `Struct`.